# Error ao tentar implementar o Swagger em minha API

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, hapijs

Boa noite, estou tentando implementar o Swagger em minha api porem é apresentado o seguinte erro em meu console

```
(node:28024) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Plugin hapi-swagger missing dependency @hapi/inert
(node:20248) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:20248) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

meu codigo é bem simples

```
//importo os modulos
const HapiSwagger = require('hapi-swagger')
const Vision = require('vision')
const Inert = require('inert')

//crio meu plugin custom
const Swagger = {
        info:{
            title:'Api Herois - #NodeBr',
            version: 'v1.0'
        }
}
//tento realizar o registro
 await app.register([
        Vision,
        Inert,
        {
            plugin: HapiSwagger,
            options:Swagger
        }
    ])
```

Comment: caso seja preciso eu posto o código inteiro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ao seguir a documentação https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-swagger e alterar o config das route seguindo a documentação do Hapi https://hapi.dev/tutorials/validation/?lang=en_US passando o os parametros validate para o JOI.object() o problema foi resolvido.